# How to Code Star Patterns without Conditional Logic in Visual C++? For Beginners

Tags: c++, variables, tabs, char, newline

I was looking for the exact answer for my totally *noob* question, but I couldn't found the right one, so I'm here to ask you. 
**Why I can't print the star-triangles of the image under the code?** My task is to use variables: "character output" (cout) + character literals: "newline" ("\n") + tab ("\t) and nothing more. I thought that I should put them in every single line, but clearly I was wrong. I couldn't use the output manipulator (flush) to continue at the same line without space or new row (maybe because I don't use the proper compiler and IDE for it).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZCcU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw3cI.jpg)

I hope to find the answer faster than you can publish it, even though I won't mind if you like to be my companion with my first steps of my IT adventure. :)

Cheerz!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpc7Y.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlTgP.jpg)

Comment: @Swordfish does it? omg, I should go and get read the first chapters again

Comment: @user463035818 *I should go and get read the first chapters again* – With a C++-gold badge? You're kidding me??

Comment: @Swordfish reputation/badges dont mean a thing. If anything then my reputation reflects my curiosity

Comment: Please do include the code in the question and errors if there are any. If the output is not what you expect you shuold include actual and expected output in the question.

Comment: Not sure if I should feel inferior of you, even if I get your acting as a sign that the only thing you do is trying to put me down. As I said the task is very clear: cout + \n + \t. Doesn't matter if the result is the same with all of the logic possibilities... Can you answer the question? Do you have any useful suggestions?

Comment: there must be some misunderstanding. Nobody is trying to put you down. To the contrary. We are trying to help you. However, to do that we need your code. I cannot copy paste the image you posted to compile it and see what it does

Comment: @user463035818 http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.6 and kudos for being so curious ;)

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers *My task is to use [...]* – yes, ok, but to achieve what exactly? what is the output you want to generate? At least for me that is a mystery, even after reading your question multiple times.

Comment: @Swordfish the expected output is at the bottom of the image ... ;) though to me it looks like output should be either a,b,c or d while code looks like all at once. [mcve] would help to clarify

Comment: Unfortunately I'm technically low-educated, so I can't quote the code with shortcuts Ctrl+K, with 4 spaces or... whatever. I read the explanations for help, but it doesn't work. Maybe my code is even that false than Stack Overflow don't want to print it. :D

Comment: @user463035818 Ah, scrolling solves the mytery. ^^

Comment: just put the code there, i'll do the formatting if thats the problem

Comment: It's impossible to be impossible, because I've seen that is possible, but on the Internet, there's no solution. I can't understand how can that it be?

Comment: there must be something missing. are you allowed to use the "*" character?

Comment: Assuming ASCII you can get `'*'` with `(char)(4 * '\n' + 2 * ('\n' - '\t'))` and `' '` with `(char)(3 * '\n' + 2 * ('\n' - '\t'))` ^^ The rest is a writing exercise.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers *without Conditional Logic* – loops are allowed?

Comment: Nothing is allowed. I still can't C/P the code. Why? I can't insert an image of my exact moves, so here you are the comment I receive: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers:  I don't see how you can print more than one star, in a compact program, without conditional logic.  If you use loops, they need a *termination* condition, which is conditional logic.  You could put the entire pattern of stars into one `cout` statement, which would avoid conditional logic.  However, `cout` uses conditional logic under the hood.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers *my first steps of my IT adventure.* – That has nothing to do with IT or CS then. It is just a matter of how versed you are using a text editor and find&replace ^^

Answer (score 3):

`' '` can be calculated with: `(char)(3 * '\n' + 2 * ('\n' - '\t'))`
`'*'` can be calculated with: `(char)(4 * '\n' + 2 * ('\n' - '\t'))`

Clarification:
Given ASCII is used, `'\t'` equals `9` and `'\n'` equals `10`. To get the values of `' '` (`32`) and `'*'` (`42`) simply take 3 or 4 times 10 and add 2. To get 2 use 2 times the difference of 10 and 9:

32 = 3 * 10 + 2 * (10 - 9)
42 = 4 * 10 + 2 * (10 - 9)

Here you are:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
    std::cout << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(3*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\t' << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << (char)(4*'\n'+2*('\n'-'\t')) << '\n';
}
```

#### Output:

```
*               **********      **********               *
**              *********        *********              **
***             ********          ********             ***
****            *******            *******            ****
*****           ******              ******           *****
******          *****                *****          ******
*******         ****                  ****         *******
********        ***                    ***        ********
*********       **                      **       *********
**********      *                        *      **********
```

If casts `(char)` are banned as well then use `std::cout.put()` instead of `operator<<`.
If multiplication is banned, replace with repeated addition.
If the use of integer literals is banned, replace them with multiple addition of `('\n'-'\t')`.
If addition and subtraction are banned, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want from you to do the thing instead of me, because I have nothing in return, also you don't do me a favour. I want to learn how to do it - is that simple. Your way is far more difficult that I want. That is not the easiest solution. You include operators which made the situation hard understandable for person on basic level. Sorry... Self-education is not always the best decision to make. The sad part is that paid education not offer something better. I'll give myself away and also I rather kill myself than continue that torture and nightmare.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers *I hope to find the answer faster than you can publish it* – ??? – *Your way is far more difficult that I want. That is not the easiest solution.* – How can you possibly tell that it is not the easiest solution when you don't know of \*any\* working solution at all? – *You include operators which made the situation hard understandable for person on basic level.* – feel free to ask about things you don't understand.

Comment: I saw with my own eyes one person who made the ******* triangles with no algorithms. I can't remember how, because I didn't understand the terminology then. Now I'm sure that he didn't use arithmetic or conditional operators, nor logic, loops, forms, methods, arrays, etc. It was short and easy. How is that possible to can't find the solution in the whole web? I'm shocked and nervious and I want to give up. There is no point of doing that. There're things that I understand and I'm good at... that's the one thing that I don't understand and I'm not good at.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers Given only `std::cout`, `'\t'` and `'\n'` it is not possible to do at all without calculating the values needed to represent space and star characters.

Comment: I wish I could argue, but I can't prove anything. Anyways, if you want, please, look at the second photo which I attached. Why I can do the first two triangles, but the second ones - they are asymmetric and useless.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers Loogink at your 2nd picture I see that you are now using `"*"`?? What you are using are string literals (enclosed in `"` btw, not character literals which would be enclosed in `'`). Writing `"*""*""*"` has the same effect as writing `"***"` because they get concatenated in a very early stage of the compiler translating your program.

Comment: Yes, why is that surprizes you? I used stars even at the beginning. o.O  No, I'm not using "*" as multiplicator, but as symbol.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers You said *character literals: "newline" ("\n") + tab ("\t) and nothing more.* in your question. Now that you use `"*"`, what keeps you from using `" "` too?

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers *No, I'm not using `"*"` as multiplicator, but as symbol.* – I never said you were using it as multiplicator? All I tried to explain to you was, that when you write `"a""b""c"` in your code, it has the same effect as writing `"abc"`.

Comment: Is that changes anything? Maybe I don't know English good enough to formulate my articles. Even there I say "star triangles" - shapes made by "*" 's.

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers Your question was (not only by me) understood as "I want to print pretty triangles displayed with stars but only use `'\n'` and `'\t'`." The triangles 3 and 4 in your last picture don't look like you want them because in #3 the space characters in your code between `<<` and the first `"` are meaningless for the output generated. There could be any number of them, the result wouldn't change. In #4 you are using tab characters in front of the stars which get displayed by a number of space characters usually 4 or 8. Again: Why not simply use `" "`?

Comment: I tried with spaces - it works! Great! It's so simple. But as usual it's not completely fine - you can check the newest pic - one of them doesn't want to change its position. I realise how stupid is that subject, but I can't move on if I can't find a solutions for the first exercises...

Comment: @Ms.SmartyTrousers Next step: Remove all `""` in your code.